# How to sort filename duplicates numerically, with unnumbered filename first?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, filesystems, sorting

I have a list of files with the same name, but with numbers appended (see image).

Like this:

```
Target practice (01)
Target practice (02) 
Target practice (03)
Target practice
```

How does one make windows explorer place the unnumbered file first in the sorting order, like this:

```
Target practice
Target practice (01)
Target practice (02)
Target practice (03)
```

---

I've been searching everywhere for this, but I don't know the right keywords to filter out all irrelevant finds in google.

NOTE: I want to point out that this is NOT about turning off numerical sorting so that 111 < 22 < 3. I want normal numerical sorting. But I want the first, unnumbered file to actually be first in the sorting.

If anyone knows how to make Windows do this instead:

```
Target practice (01)
Target practice (02)
Target practice (03)
Target practice (04)
```

so that the first/original file is also automatically numbered, then that will also work.

---

Windows 8

Comment: The space character comes before the period character when sorting.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the space between the `e` and the left paren (`(`) in the numbered file names comes before the period (`.`) in an unnumbered file name. The space character comes before any other printable character, so it will come first. If you eliminate the space and the parenthesis, just append the number to the file name, it will sort the way you want.

Comment: Any way to change this? It's Windows that adds the space and parentheses for me. Can I either change the sorting order, or have windows add the numbers without space and parentheses?

Comment: If you search for `windows sort order` you will find a bunch of hits, including from the Microsoft Community, where there is a question much like yours.

Comment: I'm looking through it now, but it seems like all the answers are about how to turn off Numerical sorting. So making 111 < 22 < 3. I want to keep the sorting as it is - but have what I consider to be the first filename (which is unnumbered) appear at the top.

Comment: That's not what numerical value means. It means it uses the numerical value of the text characters, not looking at an entire number.

Comment: You can change it to sort by strings (default) or by text. Those are your options. You don't like the idea of text sorting, so you are stuck with what you have. From one answer: "_I guess that what I'm trying to say is you may have to adapt your filenames to suit the W7 sort order, rather than the other way round. I'm sure a lot of thought went into determining the order most likely to satisfy the majority of users (otherwise why would they have changed the system between Win2K and XP?)._"

Comment: Hmm. Did this behaviour change between Windows 7 and 8? I cannot repro this on Windows 7.